# How can I check that a branch doesn't have any merges?

Tags: git, merge, branch

How can I check that a branch doesn't have any merges?  Specifically I think I want to check there are no merge commits between a given base commit and a given target commit.  For example, I want to detect when either of these cases happens:

```
target     o
          /|
         o |
          \|
           o
           |
base       o


target     o
           |
           |
           o
          /|
         / |
base     | o
         \ |
          \|
           o
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is surprisingly simple in the end.  You may or may not want `--ancestry-path` here too:

```
git rev-list base..target --merges --count
```

(or `base^@..target` to inspect `base` itself, but probably you don't want to inspect base, which is probably allowed to be a merge itself).

#### Description

As a general rule, we almost always want `git rev-list` to enumerate commits.  This command is more or less the plumbing equivalent of `git log`.  The range we want is "all commits reachable from the target, excluding all commits reachable from the base", so that's `base..target`.

Next, you want to enumerate only the *merges* in this list.  So we add `--merges`, which does not affect the revision walking, but does avoid listing anything but merge commits (commits with two or more parents).

We don't really care *which* commits are the merges.  We just want to know if there are any.  So if we got a count of merges, instead of the list of merges, that would suffice.  Adding `--count` tells `git rev-list` to produce the count instead of the list.

If the result is not zero, there are merges.

#### Ancestry-path

The question of whether to use `--ancestry-path` is something only you can answer.  Consider:

```
o  (target) commit blah
|\
o |  commit bar
| o  commit foo
o |  (base) commit quux
| o  commit baz
: |
: :
```

The list `base..target` will include commits `foo` and `baz` and earlier commits down that leg.  But these commits are not *between* the base and the target, as they are not descendants of base commit `quux`.

If you *do* want to consider them, leave out `--ancestry-path`.  If they should not count, include `--ancestry-path`.

Comment: For this question `--ancestry-path` is irrelevant, isn't it?  If there's anything extra in the ancestry path then that means there must have been a merge.  It might affect the count but it won't affect whether or not there were merges at all.  Can you confirm?

Comment: Yeah, on further thought, I think `--ancestry-path` won't matter here. As you said it might change the count, but for it to do so, the count will need to be at least 1. Adding `--ancestry-path` might speed up the walk, perhaps ... or might slow it down due to needing to mark more nodes in the graph during the traversal. Hard to say for sure without testing.  (Also, sorry about `--no-merges` vs `--merges` :-) that's what happens when I type in the answer while thinking / talking about other stuff real-time)

Answer (score 0):

The following command returns all the merge commits between `base` and `target`.

```
git rev-list --merges base..target
```